# Constexpr compound assignment operator in clang and gcc

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, c++14, constexpr

I have the following code:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <type_traits>

enum class FooEnum : uint8_t{
    Foo1 = 0, 
    Foo2 = 1
};

constexpr uint32_t& operator|= (uint32_t& lhs, FooEnum rhs) {
    return lhs |= 1u << static_cast<uint8_t>(rhs);
}

int main() {
    uint32_t bar{0};
    bar|=FooEnum::Foo1;
}
```

So essentially, the `|=` operator is supposed to take an enum and set the bit, whose position corresponds to its integral value.

When compiled with clang++ 3.5.0 on fedora 21, everything works fine, but when compiled with g++ 4.9.2, it throws an **error** saying that this is not a *constant-expression*:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘constexpr uint32_t& operator|=(uint32_t&, FooEnum)’:
main.cpp:16:2: error: expression ‘(lhs = (lhs | (1u << ((int)rhs))))’ is not a constant-expression
  }
  ^
```

This is true for all kinds of compiler flag combinations, but you can e.g. test it with `g++ -std=c++11 -o a.out main.cpp` (c++14 doesn't make a difference)

**So my questions are:**

1. Which of the compilers is right (and why)?
2. Is there a way to implement the `operator|=` such that g++ will accept it as a `constexpr`?

EDIT:
In case you are wondering, why I tried to declare the operator as `constexpr` in the first place although this isn't required in the example:
In my actual code, I'm using the `|=`-operator in order to implement the (constexpr) `|`-operator, which I wanted to be usable in a constexpr expression, but before that, I stumbled over the difference between the two compilers, not realizing, that gcc4.9 doesn't fully support c++14 (yet accepting the `-std=c++14` flag).
When using the operator to actually initialize a global constexpr variable, even clang only compiles it with c++14 flag.

Comment: Isn't `operator|=` inherently non-const?

Comment: @Barry: As a member function yes, but this is a free function. Also constexpr and the constness of a member function are two different concepts.

Comment: Assignment is not allowed in a C++11 constant expression. (Assignment and compound-assignment are explicitly mentioned as forbidden inside a constant expression in C++11[expr.const]/2)

Comment: @dyp: Thank you, I didn't know that, but its the same for `-std=c++14`.

Comment: "Relaxing the requirements on constexpr functions" is only [supported since gcc 5](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx1y.html). The paper linked includes allowing assignment inside constant expressions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The expression `lhs |= 1u << static_cast<uint8_t>(rhs)` can never be a constant expression itself**, because it modifies `lhs`. The rule that forbids this in C++14 is §5.19/2.15 (an effectively equivalent one exists in C++11 as well):

> A *conditional-expression* `e` is a *core constant expression* unless
>   the evaluation of `e`, following the rules of the abstract machine
>   (1.9), would evaluate one of the following expressions:
>
> - modification of an object (5.17, 5.2.6, 5.3.2) **unless it is applied
>     to a non-volatile lvalue of literal type that refers to a non-volatile
>     object whose lifetime began within the evaluation of `e`**;

In C++11, it was required to be one, due to  §7.1.5/5:

> For a `constexpr` function, if no function argument values exist such that the function invocation substitution would produce a constant expression (5.19), the program is ill-formed; no diagnostic required.

There exists no argument that makes the returned expression a constant expression after invocation substitution: The assignment prevents that. Hence the program is ill-formed in C++11 (but no diagnostic is required), and when compiling with `-std=c++11`, GCC shows compliant behavior.
In C++14 that rule was adjusted:

> For a non-template, non-defaulted `constexpr` function […], if
>   no argument values exist **such that an invocation of the function […] could be an evaluated subexpression of a core constant
>   expression (5.19)**, the program is ill-formed; no diagnostic required.

This enables the return expression itself to be a non-constant expression, as long as the function is evaluate-able inside another core constant expression, e.g. from within another `constexpr` function:

```
constexpr auto foo(FooEnum rhs)
{
    uint32_t x = 0;
    x |= rhs;
    return x;
}
```

`foo(FooEnum::Foo1)` is a core constant expression, hence `operator|=` can be invoked in a core constant expression, hence the function definition is well-formed.

As noted by @dyp in the comments, GCC only supports the "relaxing constraints on constexpr functions"-feature since version 5. [GCC 5.1 compiles your code](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/LPbhMoESpNbEFvTm).

So now the bodies of `constexpr` functions usually consist of statements that aren't constant expressions themselves. An example following the first, quoted section shows a function `incr`, which GCC would reject as well:

> ```
> constexpr int incr(int &n) {
>     return ++n;
> }
>
> constexpr int h(int k) {
>     int x = incr(k); // OK: incr(k) is not required to be a core
>                      // constant expression
>     return x;
> }
> ```

Comment: I understand that in my example, my operator isn't used in a constant expression, which is probably the reason clang accepts it even in c++11 mode and just ignores the constexpr declaration. What I don't quite understand is if  "the program is ill-formed; no diagnostic required." mean, that clang compiling this in c++11 mode is an instance of UB, or is it e.g. implementation defined? Basically I'd like to know, if I'm guaranteed to either get a compile time error or the expected behavior (constexpr being ignored, but `bar` having the right value at the end and no weird side effects).

Comment: @MikeMB Clang is allowed to compile  it in C++11-mode since it's not required to diagnose your error. I.e. it's roughly equivalent to undefined behavior.

Comment: *"an effectively equivalent one"* might be a bit of a stretch, since C++11 forbids assignments indiscriminately. But yes, it has the same effect here. (Uh, I'm starting to nit-pick)

Comment: @dyp Edit as you wish, I'm too lazy to do that now :D